# Can't download gradle 8.0.0

Tags: android, gradle

```
I'm getting an error in the console, who understands, help me solve
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0-alpha09.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.0.0-alpha09/gradle-8.0.0-alpha09.pom
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.0.0-alpha09/gradle-8.0.0-alpha09.pom
Required by:
    project :
Add google Maven repository and sync project
Open File
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gUyL.png)

Looked for a solution on the Internet, but all to no avail

Comment: do you have `google()` in repositories section ?

Comment: Yes, the default was

Answer (score 0):

The last lines say `Add google Maven repository and sync project`. You can click on "Open file" to see the file and by clicking on `Add google Maven repository and sync project`, you can add google repositories to your project.

If the issue exists, clean Android Studio caches using `File>Invalidate caches`. Also, check your Internet or proxy and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can put a build gradle like the one below.

***build.gradle(Project Level)***

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_ui_version = '1.5.0-alpha02'
        kotlin_version = '1.8.10'
    }
        dependencies {
            // Add this line
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
            classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.5'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.44' apply false
}
```